# Enabling C++ standards when compiling GEOS using cmake/ccmake?

Tags: c++, geos, compile

I read from RFC # 7 of GEOS that the old autoconf based build system may be removed in the future, in favor of using `cmake`.

I sometimes need to customize geos and add functions that uses the newest C++ features (e.g. c++17). I know how to enable such features on the command line with autoconf, but

How to enable e.g., c++17 in the cmake system?

-- EDIT --

I have looked in SO, and the answers there suggest adding things to CMAKE files. However, I use `ccmake`, and do not want to edit any cmake files.

Also, to clarify, one reason I ask here instead of SO, is that GEOS is a common GIS package which may or may not be intended for C++17. The adoption of C+11 happened only recently.

That's why I think it's better to ask about future GEOS options here, rather than SO.

Comment: Compiler questions are in the domain of [so]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be done without editing `CMakeLists.txt`. The GEOS `CMakeLists.txt` has a `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` statement that overrides anything specified from the command line (so you can't do `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17`, for example). I guess we could change that in GEOS. I'd suggest sending an email to the [`geos-devel`](https://lists.osgeo.org/listinfo/geos-devel) list explaining the need to compile with C++17.